# Same subcategory for all Main categories in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a question about category in Wordpress.
I have a website about travel, so there have many place, so I use category for each place, and in each place there are the same some sub-catergories. Are there anyway, which I just create sub-categories one time and apply it for all main-categories, because sub-categories is same in all main-categories.

For example:

1. New York : Food, Nightlife
2. London : Food, Nightlife
3. Paris : Food, Nighlife

With New York, London, Paris is main categories level 1, and Food, Nightlife is sub categories level 2. As you see, sub-categories same for all main categories. Because I have many main categories, so I want to find a fast way to do this.

Thank for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a list of Categories and Sub-categories you can have a look at the template tag `wp_list_categories` in the [WP codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).